# Porque está dando esses erros? #Formulários de cadastramento

Tags: php, html

Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\cadastrando.php on line 10

e assim vai com todos os POSTS.....

o estranho é que quando eu mudo do português para o inglês, o mesmo não dá nenhum erro. Tipo, se mudar==> $nome=$_POST9('name'); da certo. Mas quando eu coloco em portugês da erro. Lembrando que no banco de dados está em português e na parte dos formulários estão de acordo, o que pode ser?
Segue código abaixo:

```html
<html><title>Cadastre-se</title>
<meta charset="UNICODE"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/tema_Principal.css"> 
<body>
<hr>
<form name="signup" method="POST" action="cadastrando.php"/>
NOME:      <input type="text" name="nome"/><br><br>
SOBRENOME: <input type="text" name="sobrenome"/><br><br>
E-MAIL:    <input type="text" name="email"/><br><br>
ESTADO     <input type="text" name="estado"/><br><br>
CIDADE     <input type="text" name="cidade"/><br><br>
País     <input type="text"   name="pais"/><br><br>
SENHA:     <input type="password" name="senha"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="submit">
<hr>

</form>



</body>




</html>






PARTE DO SISTEMA DE CADASTRO

<?php

$host ="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db_base="banco_de_dados";
$conectar = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_base) or die(mysql_error());

$nome= $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome= $_POST['sobrenome'];
$senha= $_POST['senha'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$cidade= $_POST['cidade'];
$estado= $_POST['estado'];
$pais= $_POST['pais'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Usuarios(nome, senha, email, sobrenome, cidade, estado, pais) VALUES('$nome','$senha', '$email','$sobrenome', '$cidade', '$estado', '$pais')");
?>

<html>

<title>Cadastrando...</title>

</html>
```

Comment: Cole o código PHP e Formulário todo, pra gente analisar...

Comment: porque você colocou $_POST9 na pergunta? não existe global $_POST9.

Answer (score 0):

Alguns erros acontecem na hora de criar e enviar o formulário, segue abaixo uma solução básica que poderá te ajudar:

**HTML**

```
<html><title>Cadastre-se</title>
<meta charset="UNICODE"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/tema_Principal.css"> 
<body>
<hr>
    <form name="signup" action="cadastrando.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"/>
        NOME:      
        <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"/><br><br>
        SOBRENOME: 
        <input type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome"/><br><br>
        E-MAIL:    
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/><br><br>
        ESTADO     
        <input type="text" id="estado" name="estado"/><br><br>
        CIDADE     
        <input type="text" id="cidade" name="cidade"/><br><br>
        País     
        <input type="text" id="pais" name="pais"/><br><br>
        SENHA:     
        <input type="password" id="senha" name="senha"/><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$host ="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db_base="banco_de_dados";
$conectar = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_base) or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $senha= $_POST['senha'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $cidade= $_POST['cidade'];
    $estado= $_POST['estado'];
    $pais= $_POST['pais'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Usuarios(nome, senha, email, sobrenome, cidade, estado, pais) VALUES('$nome','$senha', '$email','$sobrenome', '$cidade', '$estado', '$pais')");
}
?>
```

Comment: Passa a solução com mysqli...Muda quase nada mesmo...

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/><!-- Aqui precisa ser utf-8 -->
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<html><title>Cadastre-se</title>
<meta charset="UNICODE"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/tema_Principal.css"> 
<body>
<hr>
<form name="signup" method="POST" action="cadastrando.php"/>
NOME:      <input type="text" name="nome"/><br><br>
SOBRENOME: <input type="text" name="sobrenome"/><br><br>
E-MAIL:    <input type="text" name="email"/><br><br>
ESTADO     <input type="text" name="estado"/><br><br>
CIDADE     <input type="text" name="cidade"/><br><br>
País     <input type="text"   name="pais"/><br><br>
SENHA:     <input type="password" name="senha"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="submit">
<hr>

</form>



</body>




</html>






PARTE DO SISTEMA DE CADASTRO

<?php

$host ="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db_base="banco_de_dados";
$conectar = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_base) or die(mysql_error());

$nome= $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome= $_POST['sobrenome'];
$senha= $_POST['senha'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$cidade= $_POST['cidade'];
$estado= $_POST['estado'];
$pais= $_POST['pais'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Usuarios(nome, senha, email, sobrenome, cidade, estado, pais) VALUES('$nome','$senha', '$email','$sobrenome', '$cidade', '$estado', '$pais')");
?>

<html>

<title>Cadastrando...</title>

</html>
```